# Creating an Oracle SQL Table from another table and an identity column

Tags: sql, oracle

I usually use this code to create a new table from existing tables:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_NEW
AS
SELECT 'TEST' AS TEST_COLUMN,
        PRS_ID AS TABLE_ID
FROM TABLE_OLD
```

How do I insert an identity column into TABLE_NEW. So I will have 3 columns in TABLE_NEW, ID, TEST_COLUMN and TABLE_ID?

ID could be defined as

```
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Create the table first.

Use a sequence, and you can create one like this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE myseq
START WITH     1
INCREMENT BY   1
NOCACHE
NOCYCLE;
```

Then use:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (col1, col2, col3) 
SELECT myseq.nextval, foo1, foo2 
FROM table1
```

Comment: I get this error: "ORA-02287: sequence number not allowed here". The error is on the myseq.nextval line

Comment: Thanks Peter. The problem with doing an insert into is that the table is pretty wide - 122 columns. I would have to re-write a lot of code.

As a temp fix, I'm just running an ALTER TABLE command and using the  myseq.nextval there. Its not good code, but it works for now.

Comment: Great! Have a nice weekend!